# Software for keeping logs

Tags: software-recommendation, log

In the book "Agile developer" of Pragmatic bookshelf there is such concept as "*solution log*" - file with problems and notes on their solutions. ie:
[image: screenshot of file]

Now I do it either in *LibreOfficeWriter* or in *gedit*. Software for keeping notes (like *Google Keep*) is too lightweight.

Are there some applications on Ubuntu for this log-wiki-like file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to able to keep stuff like this under version control, so I prefer text-based solutions (you mentioned gedit, for example).

I find plain-text to be too limiting, and not very friendly for non-technical people, so I tend to use restructured text (you could use markdown, or whatever form of light-weight markup you prefer) and pandoc (`sudo apt-get install pandoc`) - pandoc converts between various text formats, and can output HTML, PDF (via LaTeX) and various word-processor formats.

If you have a lot of documentation, you could consider using [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/)  (python: `pip install -U Sphinx`) - it also uses restructured text - but Sphinx would probably be overkill if you're only concerned about a solutions log.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `plod - Personal LOgging Device` since 1993. See [Hal Pomeranz's Paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/lisa93/pomeranz.html)

Abstract

PLOD (the Personal LOgging Device) is a simple text interface which allows System Administrators (and others) to keep a record of the work they do from day to day. The program was developed in Perl with device independence, flexibility, extensibility, and ease of use in mind. The user interface is reminiscent of Berkeley mail, complete with many pre-defined tilde-escapes which perform various useful functions. Users may easily extend the program by defining their own personal escape sequences.